# Can't mask IRQ using PIC

Tags: c, assembly, osdev

I've been trying to setup interrupts in an x86_64 protected mode kernel in order to use the keyboard interrupt. I have loaded the IDT, remapped the PIC, the keyboard IRQ works but I keep receiving INT 8 which seams to indicate a double fault. I have tried masking the timer interrupt(IRQ0) which also doesn't work, masking all interrupts seams to do nothing. What am I doing wrong?

pic.h:

```
#pragma once
#define PIC1_COMMAND 0x20
#define PIC1_DATA    0x21
#define PIC2_COMMAND 0xA0
#define PIC2_DATA    0xA1

#define NEW_IRQ_0 0x20
#define NEW_IRQ_8 0x28

#define ICW1_INIT    0x10
#define ICW1_ICW4    0x01
#define ICW4_8086    0x01

void remap_pic()
{
    uint8_t pic1_mask, pic2_mask;

    pic1_mask = inb(PIC1_DATA);
    pic2_mask = inb(PIC2_DATA);

    outb(PIC1_COMMAND, ICW1_INIT | ICW1_ICW4);
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC2_COMMAND, ICW1_INIT | ICW1_ICW4);
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC1_DATA, NEW_IRQ_0);
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC2_DATA, NEW_IRQ_8);
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC1_DATA, 0x4);
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC2_DATA, 0x2);
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC1_DATA, ICW4_8086);
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC2_DATA, ICW4_8086);
    io_wait();

    outb(PIC1_DATA, pic1_mask);
    outb(PIC2_DATA, pic2_mask);
}
```

idt.c:

```
void idt_init() {
    for(uint64_t t = 0; t < 256; t++) {
        _idt[t].zero = 0;
        _idt[t].offset_low = (uint16_t)(((uint64_t)&isr1 & 0x000000000000ffff));
        _idt[t].offset_mid = (uint16_t)(((uint64_t)&isr1 & 0x00000000ffff0000) >> 16);
        _idt[t].offset_high = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)&isr1 & 0xffffffff00000000) >> 32);
        _idt[t].ist = 0;
        _idt[t].selector = 0x08;
        _idt[t].types_attr = 0x8e;
    }
    remap_pic();
    outb(0x21, 0xfd);
    outb(0xa1, 0xff);
    load_idt();
}

extern void isr1_handler() {
    uint8_t scancode = inb(0x60);
    print_char(SCANCODE_LOOKUP_TABLE[scancode]);
    outb(0x20, 0x20);
    outb(0xa0, 0x20);
}
```

idt_asm.asm

```
extern _idt
idtDescriptor:
    dw 4095
    dq _idt

    %macro PUSHALL 0
        push rax
        push rcx
        push rdx
        push r8
        push r9
        push r10
        push r11
    %endmacro

    %macro POPALL 0
        pop r11
        pop r10
        pop r9
        pop r8
        pop rdx
        pop rcx
        pop rax
    %endmacro

extern isr1_handler
isr1:
    PUSHALL
    call isr1_handler
    POPALL
    iretq
    global isr1

load_idt:
    lidt[idtDescriptor]
    sti
    ret
    global load_idt
```

Comment: "IRQ8 which seams to indicate a double fault" A fault doesn't send an IRQ.

Comment: This is not a [mcve] so we can't test this. Also, use the exception info or your debugger to pinpoint the reason for the fault. You may very well be invoking or returning from your handler incorrectly.

Comment: @ecm My mistake, I meant "Interrupt"

Comment: @Jester The "Minimal Reproducible Example" is way too big to post here. I only posted the faulty code, the double fault is triggered continually which is what led me to believe the timer(PIT) is causing it

Comment: @Jester I added the isr code above in case someone wants to review it

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am completely aware, I just want to get it somewhat working by before implementing it properly, why can’t I mask the timer? Or any of the IRQs for that matter?

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes, 64-bit protected mode, everything during the boot process works fine, and if I have to I will put up on GitHub

Comment: If you put it on Github I can take a look at it. Often problems people experience with OSDev are often unrelated to the code they show or are a result of build problems etc. Even though I will take a look at Github for you (remember to provide scripts and/or makefiles to build the code) I highly recommend getting a hold of BOCHS as it will usually issue warnings before a problem and can be used to find bugs in the early stages of OS development.

Comment: AFAICT, you're trying to use the 8259 PIC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8259 and https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2018/readings/hardware/8259A.pdf in 64 bit mode. Although, it _may_ be doable, no modern OS uses it. They use the APIC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller The APIC appeared long before 64 bit mode, so the combination you're using is [probably] untested. The 8259 has glitches. I'd use the APIC. But, if you want additional info on the 8259, see my answer: [Intel 8259 PIC - Acknowledge interrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34322606/5382650)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ok, I've made the project available on GitHub: https://github.com/ConstantinZpher/COS.git

Comment: No crash here. Is the code in the git repo supposed to crash?

Comment: @Jester No, but I keep getting a double fault, and if I remove the double fault handler it will crash, what doesn’t make sense is why setting the IMR(interrupt mask register) on the pic does absolutely nothing, how can I mask the timer to stop it from double faulting?

Comment: For starters, you use `outb` wrong as it expects `(value, port)` but you pass `(port, value)`. Since that seems to be consistent across the code, it's probably easier to swap the operands of `outb`. Also your makefile is broken as it does not consider header files as dependencies. And you don't even have a `clean` target.

Comment: Also note you will get key release events as well. Seems to work here without faults in both qemu and bochs.

Comment: @Jester Thanks! The problem was "outb" I feel like an idiot, I thought the PIC was not responding to commands...